# Are missing certificate chains a reason for AUTHORITY INVALID?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I have recently installed a new SSL certificate on Apache 2.x with openssl and have a user report to not be able to access the page. He does the error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Although I could not reproduce the problem, a check on the SSL certificate revails some issues with a chain:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=static.watchgurus.net

Is there some cert missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the certificate is missing the IA (Intermediate Authority), or possibly the layout of the certificate is wrong.

On my Nginx I have it as:

1. Server
2. IA
3. Private Key

Is this what yours looks like?

**EDIT:**
Let me try and clear things up a bit, you would have had to generate a CSR and private key when requesting your certificate. After which your SSL provider would have sent you a bundle including the following, dependent on what format you requested the certificate to be sent.

- CA Root Certificate
- IA Certificate (They sometimes send 2)
- Server Certificate

Use a text editor to open the above mentioned certificates, also create a new called *static.watchgurus.net.pem*.

You can now paste the Server, IA and Private Keys in this order and save the .pem. Use [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) to open the newly created .pem, it should show the IA then have a little branch down showing static.watchgurus.net.

Like this:
[Google Certificate Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7rne.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I check that? Do you mean the certificate itself or the configuration of apache?

Comment: I mean the certificate itself. You should have received a certificate bundle from your provider, this will contain the IA (maybe 2 of them) and the root. You can use a text editor to string these individual files together and create your own certificate. I personally use a .pem consisting of the above, you can use https://keystore-explorer.org/ to open the certificate you created and confirm the validity.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Thank you. Now a bit clearer, but I am still strugling. My provider gave me access to the following certs: CRT, INTERMEDIATE, ROOT (CA). It is not entirly clear to me in which order they need to go from your description and other docs. I leaned that the ROOT (CA), should not be included.

Comment: I believe I got it working now. The provider hat two INTERMEDIATE crt in one field placed underneath of each other with a button "copy to clipboard". The order apeared to be wrong, I changed the order by hand and now it looks like it is working from what I see inside ssllabs. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Nice one, the chain looks good now, but I would even go as far as dropping the "USERTrust RSA Certification Authority " IA. Additionally, it's still being marked with a "B" grade on SSL Labs, this appears to be because of the ciphers you are using on Nginx. Do you have any "proxy_ssl_ciphers" set in your directives?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. As it is working now (even with grade B), I am leaving it as it is for the moment. Might be a reason because nginx is behind apache and will get the forward headers.